# How to handle a Web application based on state location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, subdomain

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to handle my Web application based on state location. That is, I would like to handle that by using different databases (one for each state) and subdomains like `www.uk.mywebsite.com`, `www.be.mywebsite.com`, etc.

**How can I do that? What do you advice about?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [geoip service/database](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Ruby&q=geoip&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=26&y=11) or if you target new devices [HTML5 geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

https://github.com/priithaamer/geoip-rails
http://geokit.rubyforge.org/

every IP in the world is tied to an organization and location (https://www.arin.net/ for US or  http://www.ripe.net/ for EU zones etc). you essentially need to be able to determine the registered location of the source ip they are coming from and route accordingly based on that.